# Django, Display uploaded image URL in template

Tags: python, django

I'm currently learning how to upload and display images in Django but I've run into a block where I can't figure out how to call the images location from the database and then display it in a template... What am I missing?

settings

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/chr/Desktop/DJANGO-APP/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_description = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_name

class Image(models.Model):
    product_image = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image')
```

views

```
def productpage(request, product_image_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_image_id)
    render(request, 'polls/productpage.html', {'product': product})
```

html

```
<h1>{{ product.product_name }}</h1>
<br>
{{ product.product_description  }}
<br>
{{ product.image.url }}
```

EDIT:

urls.py (main)

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: can you show your main urls.py?

Comment: adding to question now.

Comment: in the admin panel in the models can you open the image link and render it?

Comment: Yes, I already dealt with that issue

Comment: I think it is that you don't link your query with the model Image. try make a query calling the image model instead of the product one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def productpage(request, product_image_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Image, product_image=product_image_id)
    render(request, 'polls/productpage.html', {'product': product})
```

I guess product_image_id refers to the product ID?

Comment: yes it does. It is created when "syncdb" is run and there is a ForeignKey present (product_image in Images)